# Why is the process named geod in my iOS simulator trying to access irs.gov?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-simulator

I'm developing an app that has absolutely nothing to do with anything other than specific external audio-related hardware. While running my app in the iOS simulator, I got a message from my LittleSnitch (that's a firewall) that the process `geod (iOS)` is trying to access `irs.gov`. As if that wasn't enough, the next attempt was to `azadiradio.org`. I blocked both but I'm wondering: what is going on within my iOS simulator?

Comment: What simulator are you using? Is this in Xcode?

Comment: @NathanLucy yes, iPad simulator with iOS 7.1. There is no additional software installed other than my app and the default stuff. Could it be the Newsstand or something? But why IRS?

Comment: Are you sure that LittleSnitch is providing you with reverse dns properly?  I have heard of issues with reverse dns and Little Snitch.  It is likely that you are providing location information to less nefarious folks than the IRS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sounds like a classic case of bad [reverse DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup). Note that both the IRS and `azadiradio.org` are at least [partially hosted](http://www.irs.gov.ipaddress.com/) by Akamai's servers. This can lead to some confusion for people trying to do a reverse DNS. Your simulator might be trying to access some other server (could be Apple's, they also use Akamai) and Little Snitch tries to translate that IP address into a domain. When that IP is used by one of the world's largest hosting and content distribution networks, you run into problems.